# Is there a way to browse and upload images directly from stack.imgur?

Tags: support, imgur, uploader

As an editor for the blog, I use the images from stack.imgur.  However in order for me to use them, I have to get the link from the posts themselves or if they're my own images, or images I've found online, I have to create a dummy post and upload the images.  Is there a way to access and browse the stack.imgur photos?  I'm hoping to be able to upload, search by userid, postid, etc,.  If not, is there consideration of enabling this for users?

Comment: I have a feeling this feature is not available by design, as it might open a whole new set of issues for imgur (rights claims, flagging offensive stuff, etc.)

Comment: I'm sensing an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here... The uploading can probably be implemented natively in the blog. I don't think the user and post information is even stored but can be easily found through Data.SE.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to use images that are already in "Stack Imgur," and/or avoid uploading duplicates, so adding an uploader to the blog wouldn't really solve his problem.

Comment: @PopularDemand that's exactly my dilemma.

Comment: Don't worry about the cost of exact duplicates; if Imgur cares they can always deduplicate by hashing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to access and browse the stack.imgur photos?

Use a site search to browse, such as the following:

https://www.google.com/search?q=imageurl:i.stack.imgur.com&tbm=isch

https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=host%3Ai.stack.imgur.com&form=QBIR

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=i.stack.imgur.com&ia=images

**References**

- [Google Advanced Image Search](http://www.google.com/advanced_image_search)
- [Google Search Operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en)
- [What's the new URL for a Google Images "Quick Search" bookmark in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/365675/)
- [Google Custom Search API Search Image by Image URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591768/)
- [Three new features in Live Search Images](https://blogs.bing.com/search/2007/07/27/three-new-features-in-live-search-images/)
- [Bing Image Search Updates Roll Out Today](https://blogs.bing.com/search/2012/06/21/bing-image-search-updates-roll-out-today/)
- [Search Engine URL script: mappings.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brigand/homepage/master/js/mappings.js)
- [Why can't I see larger images in Ask.com's Image Search results?](http://help.ask.com/link/portal/30015/30018/Article/47/Why-can-t-I-see-larger-images-in-Ask-com-s-Image-Search-results)